# Kivy обращение к виджетам по id

Tags: python, kivy

Подскажите возможно ли в рамках данного кода обратится к KV - виджетам находящихся в различных областях Screen по ID.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    halign: "center"

            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

К сожалению я не понимаю каким образом можно применить метод self.ids
Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Ты можешь обратится через ScreenManager, в твоём случае self.manager.screeens[номер экрана в screenmanager].ids.<id виджета>.<его атрибут>

self.manager.screens выводит список всех экранов,
self.manager.screens[номер окна].ids - это все id этого экрана, которые ты можешь спокойно использовать